# App store in app purchase guideline for give away

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

our app has in app purchase selling additional items..I want to offer a button that says "follow us on twitter and get a free item", then if clicked, it calls Twitter API to follow.

Will this violate any apple law? For these 2 rules:

11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected.

Dropbox offers this via their web, and it seems OK, but they are dropbox.